# Switch from one view to another in the same xib file

Tags: swift3, ios11, xcode9, swift4

I have two views within a xib file. I want to perform a segue from one view to another(both views are in the same xib file). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing segue from one view to another, you can just set view to this new view. For example, currently you are in viewcontroller A with view. Now you want to set its new view (view1), just do the following

```
self.view = view1;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I think you're missing the point here. They're two views within a single XIB file. I want to switch between them.